# Match Associated With A Resource Belonging To A Namespace Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, routes, resources, matching

In my rails 4 app, I need to create a POST route that allows the admin to publish an article. I created an admin namespace that has several resources, and I want it to match the publish/unpublish actions to the articles resource that is part of the admin namespace. However, the actions map to the admin namespace and skip the articles resource.

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :articles
   post 'article/:id' => 'articles#publish'
   post 'article/:id' => 'articles#unpublish'

   resources :ads
end
```

For example, I am getting

```
admin_path   POST    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)   admin/articles#publish
             POST    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)   admin/articles#unpublish
```

Instead of the desired

```
admin_articles_path  POST    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)   admin/articles#publish
                     POST    /admin/articles/:id(.:format)   admin/articles#unpublish
```

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :articles
   post 'article/:id' => 'articles#publish'
   delete 'article/:id' => 'articles#unpublish'

   resources :ads
end
```

Sorry, but I don't think you mean 2 posts with the same path meaning different thing. I suppose the second one you mean 'delete' like above. But anyway, let's get to the point.

What's happening here is that Rails is creating a path simply called 'admin_path' because you did not specify the suffix of the name of the path you'd like. For example, you can choose:

```
post 'article/:id' => 'articles#publish', as: 'article_publish'
```

And now it will generate **'admin_article_publish_path'**

When you don't specify the suffix (or the 'as' hash), it generates only the prefix: **admin_path**

If you pay attention when you type 'rake routes' in your console, you'll see that the path **admin_articles_path** is already taken, along with **admin_article_path**; both generated by default by Rails, using the Restful name conventions.  So no, don't take that off of it. Don't take the already taken paths, that can be confusing in the future. Pick a different name. IMHO, I think that **publish_admin_articles_path** is better. It is more RESTful, following Rails convention. For that you can do:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :articles do
     post 'publish', on: :member
   end
end
```

Which will generate:

```
publish_admin_article POST   /admin/articles/:id/publish(.:format)  admin/articles#publish
```

Same reasoning for unpublish.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to clear that you **can't** have `admin_articles_path` as your route helper method for `'articles#publish'`, because it is already consumed for `'articles#index`.

```
admin_articles GET      /admin/articles(.:format)          admin/articles#index
```

Update your routes as:

```
namespace :admin do
   resources :articles
   post 'article/:id' => 'articles#publish', :as => "article_publish"
   delete 'article/:id' => 'articles#unpublish', :as => "article_unpublish"

   resources :ads
end
```

Generated Views:

```
admin_article_publish   POST     /admin/article/:id(.:format)       admin/articles#publish
admin_article_unpublish DELETE   /admin/article/:id(.:format)       admin/articles#unpublish
```

I am using `unpublish` with `delete` http verb. It's more logical. Also, you can't have same routes to point different actions.